# Can I raise an A/C Unit and platform up maybe 5 inches without disconnecting anything?

Tags: air-conditioning, copper-tubing

I know there is refrigerant in the a/c unit.  I know there is a copper wire connecting the unit to the house.  From what I am reading and from the videos I have watched, I can put a 4 by 4 under the concrete pad the ac unit currently sits on.   I can then work gravel under the concrete pad too.  I have a bunch of  gravel to go into this part of the side of the house to level it out so that it is as high as the concrete near it.

Sounds good?  Anybody recommend I NEED to have an AC expert out for this?

Comment: Is there any slack in the line set (pipes) running out of the house and to the unit? Will they move at all? That would probably be the major concern as those are usually solid and stiff, not flexible copper pipe. If you were to kink the lines, you could crack them, releasing all the refrigerant. If that happens, you'd be calling in service to replace the line set and refill the system. I'd wait for someone with more knowledge to provide an answer, but you may be safer off having someone move this for you.

Comment: Wait on this until you are replacing the condensing unit. Attempting to raise a condensing unit in the manner you describe would almost certainly damage it. What is the need? Is the bottom of the unit immersed in standing water during heavy rain?

Comment: Good point, @JimStewart, I was wondering _why_ the need to raise it, too.

Comment: I have had to lift a few outside units where the owners added sidewalks and patio’s and turned the condenser into a micro pool when the drainage was not so good. I have not cracked a line doing this but would only do it with tubing , hvac tubing is soft and comes in rolls not sticks I would not try and lift a hard line unless there was 4 or 5’

Answer (score 1):

This is such a bad idea. One of the worse sounds I have experienced is refrigerant hissing out through a pipe in a condensing unit. I tried to move a condensing unit just a inch or two so I could open up the disconnect switch to the unit to replace a contactor. The motion was enough to break the brazed connection and out came the Freon.

In addition to the refrigerant, you also have your electric supply line and a possible ground to worry about.

If you are dead set on doing this and can't wait until you replace the condensing unit as Jim Steward suggests, get an AC guy out there to remove and save your refrigerant. Then do your lifting and when done, have your refrigerant pumped back into your system.

Answer (score 0):

Most Refrigerant lines are soft copper some are flex line and if you have a few feet before they go into the house it would not be an issue to raise the outside unit, make sure raising will not be a problem with the electrical I always use flex to the outside unit but I have seen rigid conduit and EMT this would be more problematic than the copper line set. There is a risk but if there is 2-3’ free befor going in the house I would do it.
I have raised a few units where a sidewalk & patios were poured higher and turned the ac pad into a low point 1 even filled with water about 1” deep. Keep an eye on the low pressure line it is the larger one and on large units it may be pipe not soft tube. This would be more likely on units over 5 ton. You really need 2-3’ of line to raise the unit that much if you have more that will make the job easier, less than 2 -3’ or larger unit and you could create a leak.